# LINQ To Entities  .Any() results in null reference exception

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have a simple query as below:

```
Dim sizings = From a In db.Sizings
                      Where a.Customer.ID = customer.ID
                      Select a

If sizings.Any Then
    .....
```

The `sizings.Any` line is throwing a null reference exception. I thought I was meant to use `.Any` to determine if there were any rows returned?

`isnothing(sizings)`  returns `false`.

Any ideas?

**Edit - Resolution:**
Don't use null objects in the LINQ Query!

Comment: is Customer.ID nullable?

Comment: Please show us the stack trace.

Comment: Ahh, stupid. Thanks for the hints guys, the customer object I was getting the ID from was returning null after some changes.
Everything is working now :)

Answer (score 2):

Try checking that Customer isn't null before comparing its ID.

```
Dim sizings = From a In db.Sizings
              Where a.Customer IsNot Nothing And a.Customer.ID = customer.ID
              Select a

If sizings.Any() Then
   '
End If
```

Comment: the customer object I was passing was null itself so I'm pretty sure this will suffer the same null ref exception.

Comment: I think that it will work if the query uses AndAlso rather than And.  Then the evaluation of a.Customer.ID would not occur and there would be no null ref exception.

Answer (score 0):

What about using sizings.Count() > 0

Comment: I want to know why this is marked down, the count causes the enumeration to be populated and tells you if there are rows are not.  The other option is to see if sizings.FirstOrDefault() != null

Comment: Maybe because with .Any() you should achieve same results and .Count() is considerably slower.

Comment: We are asking for Customer by ID, chances are we are returning 1 or 0 rows here. Count and Any are the same.

Comment: If they are the same your suggestion won't help either.

Comment: The problem is caused by the deferred execution.  The exception was showing up on the call to Any(), but was actually caused by trying to get the value of a.Customer.ID when the a.Customer was Nothing.  The same thing would happen on the call to Count().  When Count() is called, it would then execute the query and if a.Customer is Nothing, it would throw a null ref when it tried to evaluate a.Customer.ID

Comment: @Chris Dunaway - Thanks it was the deferred execution that got me. I had issues with Any/Exists before so I have not used them in a while as a straight bool check, only in queries.  Awesome explanation of the problem